# Why shapefile() of raster package does not work?

Tags: r, raster

I have a simple r question. I  use this [.shp file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hs46mvhr4eklj9l/DJI_01041_train.shp?dl=0) and then I try to import it in rstudio with `library(raster) 
trainData <- shapefile("C:/Users/makis/Documents/Image/DJI_01041_train.shp")` but I get

```
Error in .local(x, ...) : file.exists(extension(x, ".shx")) is not TRUE
```

Why does this happen? [Here](http://amsantac.co/blog/en/2016/09/20/balanced-image-classification-r.html) it works.

Comment: Does `C:/Users/makis/Documents/Image/DJI_01041_train.shx` exist? (Emphasis on the **shx** suffix)

Comment: but it is shp not shx as you can see by yourself in the dropbox link.

Answer (score 0):

all the other files were missing from my folder (.shx,.prj ,.dbf, .cpg, .sbn, .sdf)